# Lazy loading using nodejs and mongoDB as backend data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, load, lazy-evaluation

Our collection has around 100 million documents. We created a simple application using nodejs and expressjs with a limit clause in the mongo query . It is sufficient for the users as of now. In the mean time we are trying to implement lazy loading so that the initial page load returns few documents and when the user scrolls we would like to load further documents. Struggling where to start and how to ahead to implement it. Appreciate your suggestions.
My index.js file would look like this

```
router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  var db = req.db; 
  var users = db.get('users'); 

  users.find(query, {limit: 10000}, function(e, docs){
    res.render('users', { 
      title: 'Users',
      'users': docs  
    });
  });
});
```

I would like to remove the limit and using skip trying to achieve this.
Please post your suggestions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#cursor.skip) should help. It uses the `.skip` method of the `.find()` cursor. I call it pagination rather than lazy loading.

```
var itemsPerPage = 10;

router.get('/users/:pageNum', function(req, res) {
  var db = req.db; 
  var users = db.get('users'); 
  users.find(query, {skip: (itemsPerPage * (pageNum-1)), limit: itemsPerPage},function(e, docs){
    res.render('users', { 
      title: 'Users',
      'users': docs  
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: so from where pageNum should be passed , If we do it as pagination ?

Comment: That will be part of the request you make. `http://server.tld/users/2`.
I haven't used expressjs a lot, so I'm not sure if that is how you define query params.

Comment: I also agree with @bidhan-a's suggestion to use Mongoosejs.

Comment: Thanks very much . I did it with javascript with 2 buttons namely previous and next. it works

Answer (score 0):

You could implement [paging](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#set-the-starting-point-of-the-result-set) in your route

Something like below;

```
// GET /users?start=20
router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  var db = req.db; 

  var start = parseInt(req.query.start) || 0;
  var users = db.get('users'); 

  users.find(query, {start: start, limit: 10000}, function(e, docs){
    res.render('users', { 
      title: 'Users',
      'users': docs  
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you use Mongoose to model the MongoDB objects efficiently and then make use of one of many mongoose pagination modules available.