# Ant Design Table Scroll Event

Tags: reactjs, antd

I use ant design table and I want to fix the height of table and add scroll when data is large

[antd table demo](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-fixed-header)

And I want when user scrolls to the bottom of the table, then more data is fetched from the server. But ant design table does not have the onScroll event, I cannot know when and where user scrolls to

I find these people having the same issue as me

[antd gihub](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/5904)

and they suggest to use refs and I use this ref solution but it does not work

[gist solution](https://gist.github.com/koistya/934a4e452b61017ad611)

Could you show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This issue should be resolved by two things:

1. Use `scrollToFirstRowOnChange` , it keeps position consistent after every re-render.
2. Add scroll event on the .ant-table-body.

[image]

Comment: can you give example how to add scroll event to `ant-table-body` ?

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented the same logic with React Query but you can add any logic on top of that. So it is not restricted to use React-Query.

```js
import { useCallback, useRef } from "react";

type Params = {
  isLoading?: boolean;
  hasMore?: boolean;
  fetchMore?: any;
};

export function useScrolling({ isLoading, hasMore, fetchMore }: Params) {
  const observer = useRef<any>();
  const lastReportElementRef = useCallback(
    (node: any) => {
      if (isLoading) return;
      if (observer.current) observer.current.disconnect();
      observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(async (entries) => {
        if (entries[0].isIntersecting && hasMore) {
          fetchMore();
        }
      });
      if (node) observer.current.observe(node);
    },
    [isLoading, hasMore]
  );

  return lastReportElementRef;
}

export default function ListFindings() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { isLoading, isFetching, data, hasNextPage, fetchNextPage } = useInfiniteQuery({
    queryKey: ["findings"],
    queryFn: handleFetchFindings,
    gcTime: ms("5m"),
    staleTime: ms("5m"),
    initialPageParam: 0,
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => lastPage?.nextPage,
  });
  const scrollRef = useScrolling({
    isLoading: isLoading || isFetching,
    hasMore: hasNextPage,
    fetchMore: fetchNextPage,
  });

  const findings = useMemo(() => {
    return data?.pages.flatMap((page) => page?.findings);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <>
      <Table
        bordered={false}
        rowClassName="cursor"
        pagination={false}
        rowKey="id"
        dataSource={findings as any}
        scroll={{ x: "max-content" }}
        loading={{ spinning: isLoading, indicator: <Spinner size="small" /> }}
      >
        <Column
          dataIndex="benchmark"
          title={<TableHeaderCell label="Benchmark" field="benchmark" />}
          render={(_, r) => <span className="t12-bold">{r.benchmark.toUpperCase()}</span>}
        />
        <Column
          dataIndex="severity"
          title={<TableHeaderCell label="Severity" field="severity" />}
        />
      </Table>
      {isFetching && !isLoading && (
        <Stack justify="center">
          <Spinner size="small" />
        </Stack>
      )}
      <div ref={scrollRef} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React Lazyload](https://github.com/jasonslyvia/react-lazyload) and wrap your components on frontend side. If you need backend lazy loading you can check this example: [Node.js + MongoDB example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253287/lazy-loading-using-nodejs-and-mongodb-as-backend-data) and set the amount of data you need to distribute per page

Comment: I have to use ant design for this project, Do you know how to add the onScroll event to the table?

Comment: Didn't manage to find such feature in antd table, I used lazy pagination instead of infinite scrolling to work with big data.

Comment: yeah yeah, infinite scrolling is like a modern UI

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code

```
useEffect(() => {
    const scrollableDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('ant-table-body');
    console.log(scrollableDiv[0]);
    scrollableDiv[0].addEventListener('scroll', function () {
      console.log('Scroll');
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).